# Why are these Navy machine gunners wearing gloves and masks?

Tags: sea-patrol

1. Why are these Navy machine gunners wearing gloves and masks? I've watched many films where someone fires a machine gun, but never wearing gloves and masks.
2. Why haven't their protected their eyes with goggles or full face respirators? Their eyes are exposed.

This series ante-dates COVID19, so disease prevention isn't the reason. And the patrol boat is too far from the enemy, so preventing chemical or poison gas isn't the reason.

I screenshot [37:58](https://youtu.be/hfDLeY2tdN8?t=2278) of S4E12 of *Sea Patrol* that portrays the Royal Australian Navy.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is standard [**Anti-flash gear**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-flash_gear)

> Anti-flash gear, also known simply as flash gear, is basic personal protective equipment consisting of a fire-resistant hood and fire-resistant gloves, often made of Nomex.
>
> The purpose of anti-flash gear is to provide protection to the head, neck, face and hands from short-duration flame exposure and heat. **This equipment is donned by shipboard navy personnel whenever a fire breaks out or during periods of heightened readiness**.